# Code conversion from Python to VB.NET: Working with bytes

Tags: python, vb.net

I am working on a binary file slicing: code already written in python for testing purpose. Now I am converting the code from python to vb.net.

python:

```py
img = np.fromfile(f, dtype='int16')
img1 = img[0:1024*1024]
img1 = img1.reshape([1024,1024])

img2 = img[1024*1024:2*1024*1024]
img2 = img2.reshape([1024,1024])
#similarly for next 6 slices
```

vb.net:

```vb
Dim buffc_1024_1() As Byte = New Byte((1024*1024*2)-1){}
Dim buffc_1024_2() As Byte = New Byte((1024*1024*2)-1){}

Buffer.BlockCopy(_DATA,0,buffc_1024_1,0,1024*1024)
Buffer.BlockCopy(_DATA,1024*1024,buffc_1024_2,0,1024*1024)
'similarly for next 6 slices
```

The `_DATA` is the input file read to create these 8 data slices. The first copy is properly done, but the second copy of data is incorrect, not sure if this is because of `Buffer.BlockCopy`. Unfortunately I cannot upload the binary file as its proprietary.

Comment: That code should work. I would start by just copying in chuck of 3 bytes to see what is happening, it'll be easier to check the data. Also, I don't understand why you initialize the array with a *2 and a -1.

Comment: @the_lotus Yes the file which I read is 16-bit, so as bytearray is 8-bit, I give bytearray*2 to make it uint16.. Not sure with python code file crops perfect, but with vb, the file is incorrect

Comment: Then the last parameter of BlockCopy should be 1024*1024*2

Comment: Yep, done it there is minor difference of data, but its still incorrect and not as same as output from python code

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you want to read data in chunks and each chunk's size is 1024*1024*2 bytes.

```
Dim bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2

Dim buffc_1024_1() As Byte = New Byte(bufferSize) {}
Dim buffc_1024_2() As Byte = New Byte(bufferSize) {}
Dim buffc_1024_3() As Byte = New Byte(bufferSize) {}
Dim buffc_1024_4() As Byte = New Byte(bufferSize) {}
Dim buffc_1024_5() As Byte = New Byte(bufferSize) {}
Dim buffc_1024_6() As Byte = New Byte(bufferSize) {}

Using _DATA As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\input-text.txt")
    Console.WriteLine(_DATA.Read(buffc_1024_1, 0, bufferSize))
    Console.WriteLine(_DATA.Read(buffc_1024_2, 0, bufferSize))
    Console.WriteLine(_DATA.Read(buffc_1024_3, 0, bufferSize))
    Console.WriteLine(_DATA.Read(buffc_1024_4, 0, bufferSize))
    Console.WriteLine(_DATA.Read(buffc_1024_5, 0, bufferSize))
    Console.WriteLine(_DATA.Read(buffc_1024_6, 0, bufferSize))
End Using
```

I used a text file with size of 6,839,410 bytes. First 3 read operations, the buffer are fully filled. But the 4th operation only reads 547954 bytes because there is no bytes left to read. The last 2 operations don't read any bytes. So the result of this code is:

```
2097152
2097152
2097152
547954
0
0
```

Try comparing the result of your python code and this code with a same input file (I don't have your file, so I use a random file).

**Note.**
You can remove the Console.WriteLine(_DATA.Read(...)) part. Just call _DATA.Read(...).